# как сделать так чтобы в строку вводилось n чисел и после этого с ними можно было бы работать?

Tags: python

```
k, r, n = map(int, input().split())
i = 1
sum = 0
for i in range(n):
    m = map(int, input().split()) 
    if m == k:
        sum += r
    if m < k:
        act1 = k - m
        sum += (r - act1)
    if m > k:
        sum += (r * 2)
print(sum)
```

после выполнения вылетает ошибка что с m нельзя производить операции. как исправить?

Comment: список m_list= list(map(int, input().split())) до цикла

Comment: map возвращает генератор потому что

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте варианты ввода в ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
m = map(int, input().split()) 
if m == k:
```

`m` - итерируемый объект (условно список), `k` - число, первый элемент из введенных в самом начале чисел

вы пытаетесь сравнить несравнимое

опишите задачу более подробно, что именно надо было сделать

и кстати старайтесь не использовать названия функций как переменные - это я про `sum`

Comment: мне нужно чтобы м вводилась как строка из n символов

Comment: а общая задача в чем именно заключается?